# How can I render a simple lattice in LibGDX?

Tags: opengl, java, android, libgdx, opengl-es2

I have searched all over, but I can't find what I think will be a simple answer. I am using Opengl ES 2.0, and LibGDX. I simply want to use GL_LINES primitives to create a lattice structure.

I have used shapeRenderer with the following code:
in create():

```
shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
```

in render():

```
shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
shapeRenderer.setColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
for (float i = -10; i <=10; i++) {
    for (float j = -10; j <= 10; j++){
        shapeRenderer.line(i, j, -10, i, j, 10);
        shapeRenderer.line(-10, i, j, 10, i, j);
        shapeRenderer.line(j, -10, i, j, 10, i);
    }
}
shapeRenderer.end();
```

The problem is, this is not a model instance, thus doesn't seem to use the RendererContext (GL_DEPTH_TEST, etc.). When I render the lattice this way, it either shows up entirely behind my models, or entirely in front of them (depending on the order I render them in the render method).

Is there a way to build a model which is simply a set of lines to be rendered with Opengl primitive GL_LINES? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a way. I'm not sure that it's the most performant, but it works, and the DEPTH_TEST (z-culling) is working now. Here is how I did it:

in declarations:

```java
private ModelInstance mLattice;
```

in create():

```java
ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
modelBuilder.begin();
MeshPartBuilder meshPartBuilder = modelBuilder.part("lattice", GL20.GL_LINES,
        Usage.Position, new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.GREEN)));

for (float i = -10; i <=10; i++) {
    for (float j = -10; j <= 10; j++){
        meshPartBuilder.line(i, j, -10, i, j, 10);
        meshPartBuilder.line(-10, i, j, 10, i, j);
        meshPartBuilder.line(j, -10, i, j, 10, i);
    }
}

Model latticeModel = modelBuilder.end();
mLattice = new ModelInstance(latticeModel);
instances.add(mLattice);
```

in render():

```java
modelBatch.begin(cam);
modelBatch.render(instances, environment);
modelBatch.end();
```

This solved my problem. There may be better (more efficient) ways to accomplish this, but this suits my needs at the moment. If I find something better, I'll update the answer for anyone who may stumble upon this.